# Running XCode OSX app from command line

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, shell

I'm writing a shell script which will automate a process for my team, but it requires the ability to run an application we have in XCode.

What I'm trying to do is run the app as though I were running it through XCode (pressing `CMD+R`).

I have looked through the `xcodebuild` documentation and can't find anything that is helpful.

Is there any way to do this in the terminal?

Comment: Why do you need to have Xcode involved at run-time?  More normal would be to use Xcode to build the application, then install it somewhere and run as needed.

Comment: @PhillipMills It's how we're set up. We don't have resources to change this setup right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Aggregate target in your project that specifies the existing build product as a dependency.  You can then add a script build phase that runs the application.

If you tell xcodebuild to build your new target, it will build the dependency and then execute the script.

I have a test project that creates something called "BindingTest".  The simplest script that I could think of is:

```
open ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/BindingTest.app
```